# Black stripe in PDF instead of image

Tags: c#, .net, image, pdf, itext

so I am making software for my client and when I showed him the output (PDF) strange black stripe instead of image is happening in the output.
It surprised me, because it worked nicely on my computer and also my laptop without any problems. So after I tried it on virtual machine, the same issue happened.

Left virtual machine output, right my computer
[image: Left virtual machine output, right my computer]

Header and footer stay always the same and only content is switched between pages.

The PDF page consists of three blocks: Header, Content, Footer
[image: The PDF page consists of three blocks: Header, Content, Footer]

I create the PDF by taking screenshot of the screen and switching the content and then putting the image into PDF. (The output is always printed out, so it doesn't matter).

- Main FORM is 595 x 835
- Header is 595 x 65
- Content is 595 x 705
- Footer is 595 x 65

Part of code that makes the PDF

```
FileStream PDFfile = new FileStream(PDFpath + "//" + filename + "_" + i + ".pdf", FileMode.Create);
Document Document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);
PdfWriter Writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Document, PDFfile);
Document.AddAuthor("Clientela garde");
Document.AddCreator("http://www.icsharp.eu");
Document.AddKeywords("Výpis do PDF");
Document.AddSubject("Výpis informací pro klienta");
Document.AddTitle("Finanční gramotnost");
// Výpis do stránky
Document.Open();
try
{
    Page1.Hide();
    Page2.Hide();
    Page3.Hide();
    Page4.Hide();
    Page5.Hide();


    Page1.Show();
    System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(595, 835))
    {
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rct = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new Point(bounds.Left - EcoTron.PDFCreator.ActiveForm.Location.X, bounds.Top - EcoTron.PDFCreator.ActiveForm.Location.Y), bounds.Size);
        EcoTron.PDFCreator.ActiveForm.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, rct);
        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        bitmap.SetResolution(1190, 1684);
        PdfPTable HeaderTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        HeaderTable.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
        HeaderTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
        PdfPCell ImageCell = new PdfPCell();
        ImageCell.Border = 0;
        img.ScaleAbsolute(595 - 50, 835 - 50);
        ImageCell.AddElement(img);
        HeaderTable.AddCell(ImageCell);
        Document.Add(HeaderTable);
    }
```

- [PC PDF](http://icsharp.eu/heheyx_5.pdf)
- [VIRTUAL PDF](http://icsharp.eu/gogo_3.pdf)

Comment: _I create the PDF by taking screenshot of the screen_ Sounds as if that part is not machine/screen-independent. Since we don't see it we can only guess. Are the charts from excel or MSChart or what?

Comment: You show no code, you share no PDF... How do you expect us to help?

Comment: @mkl sorry guys added info. TaW charts are just images.

Comment: Does the black border come in with that screenshot, or does it only appear so in the PDF? If it's due to your method of copying the screen, then this question is not about the "PDF" part but only about how to correct your screen copying.

Comment: @usr2564301 so I did tests and trully the problem is screen indepentent. If I increased the virtual computer resolution to 1600x1200 (1280x1024 still didn't even that my 1920x1080 works well on PC) it shows either on IMAGE and obviously on PDF too. Do you guys have any tips on fixes?

Comment: Solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

So I found what was the problem.

This line of code:

```
            System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
```

Seems that it takes Bounds only of visible window size (I'm not sure about the reason) so I changed it to this:

```
                System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
                bounds.Size = new Size(595, 835);
```

It forces the bounds to actual size of our window to screen. And now it seems the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow you described seems incredibly complicated and fragile.

Perhaps you should consider other ways of creating your document.

1. generate the document in HTML and convert the HTML to PDF (`iText7` + `pdfHTML`)
2. generate the graphics using something like `JFreeChart`, export them to a `BufferedImage` and add to the PDF directly
3. generate the graphics as SVG images, and add them to the PDF directly